# How do you manually change filters?

Tags: metro-2033

In Metro 2033 your gas mask uses filters. When a filter is getting close to being used up, your vision is obscured, mostly around the edges.

Is there a way to manually change filters so that you can clear up your vision earlier than when the filter completely runs out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To manually change your gas-mask filters, press G (default layout).

Source: [Metro 2033 default key-binding](http://www.allgame.com/game.php?id=67826&tab=controls)

Comment: I saw that it says that but I know I've tried it. Are there certain times when you are allowed to change filters?

Comment: What I read around the net: 1) Check if you have filters available. 2) Filters have varying amounts of durability (time). If the current filter has more durability then the rest, a change would not happen. 3) try to tap G twice. 4) try to hold G. For further testing, I would have to reinstall the game...

Comment: Ok cool. I did notice some seemed to last longer than others. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Press down once on the d pad..